# PHP StdClass() properties

Tags: php, function, variables, soap, stdclass

I'm having some issues with the StdClass() object in PHP..

I'm using it to send information (a string and boolean) to a function.
Outside the function, it works great.

```
$args = new StdClass();
$args->str = "hej";
$args->ic = TRUE;
fun($arg);
```

This is then the function called:

```
function fun($args) {
$str = $args->str;
$ignore_case = $args->ic;
echo $str;
echo $ignore_case;
}
```

which just writes "stric" instead of the variable contents.
Is there a way to use StdClass to transfer this data and read it correctly?

//Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function fun($args) {
 $str = $args->str;
 $ignore_case = $args->ic;
 echo $str;
 echo $ignore_case;
}
```

add `$` and second echo should be `$ignore_case` - I believe

Comment: Oh dear god, my bad... didn't help though, not it just acts like the variables are empty and prints nothing.

Comment: @Martinnj: `fun($arg);` should be `fun($args);`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `$` before the variable names in your `echo`s.

```
echo $str;
echo $ignore_case;
```

Also, `fun($arg);` should be `fun($args);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = new StdClass();
$args->str = "hej";
$args->ic = TRUE;
fun($arg);
```

Where is `$arg` defined? Your call should be `fun($args)`.

Comment: THANS! I misspelled word and everything dies... Thanks a lot!